# ERC20 Contract - OpenZeppelin - total confusion

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle, remix, erc-20

Trying to launch a simple `ERC20` Token.

I'm finding `OpenZeppelin's` extensive library - where every Contract seems to import about 4 other Contracts - to be both wonderfully well organized - but also totally confusing.

Here's a BIG question: their basic `ERC20.sol` contract *has no **`constructor()`** function.*

1) So where/how do you for example set the `totalSupply` of Tokens you want your contract to have when you deploy it?

2) where/how do you declare the `name` or `symbol` you want your Token to have?

For Q#2: I see you can "tack on" the `name`, `symbol` and `decimals` properties to your contract by also importing the `ERC20Detailed` contract - which by the way *does* have a `constructor()` - into your Contract's declaration, but then what? This still doesn't let you access `totalSupply` or the other properties of the original basic `ERC20` contract.

So how are you supposed to be doing this?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.2;


import "./ERC20Detailed.sol";


contract MyToken is ERC20, ERC20Detailed {       

    constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol, uint8 _decimals) 
        ERC20Detailed(_name, _symbol, _decimals)
        public
    {

    }


}
```

NOTE: when I try to set a value for `totalSupply` in the `public { .... }` section of the `constructor`, I get all sorts of errors...

Very confused!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also included in the library is a couple of examples - you can find them in their github repo. One, called `SimpleToken` looks like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "../token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

/**
 * @title SimpleToken
 * @dev Very simple ERC20 Token example, where all tokens are pre-assigned to the creator.
 * Note they can later distribute these tokens as they wish using `transfer` and other
 * `ERC20` functions.
 */
contract SimpleToken is ERC20 {

  string public constant name = "SimpleToken";
  string public constant symbol = "SIM";
  uint8 public constant decimals = 18;

  uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 10000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));

  /**
   * @dev Constructor that gives msg.sender all of existing tokens.
   */
  constructor() public {
    _mint(msg.sender, INITIAL_SUPPLY);
  }

}
```

Notice how the `INITIAL_SUPPLY` is set. Notice too that there is a constructor. This means if you wish to pass in the number of tokens you wish to mint in say, a truffle environment, you could rewrite that as something like:

```
  //uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 10000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));
  // REMOVE THE ABOVE LINE

  constructor(uint256 _amount) public {
    _mint(msg.sender, _amount * 10 ** uint256(decimals));
  }
```

Then, once deployed, you'll notice that the `totalSupply` amount will reflect whatever you created as the `initial_supply`.